# How to get SOCKS5 tor bridge relay proxy programatically?

Tags: bridge

As I understand it - Tor browser has the ability to retrieve a few random SOCKS5 proxy tor bridges.

I would like to integrate this functionality into one of my programs so that people can automatically access the Tor network using a random volunteer bridge without having to run Tor themselves.

What is the API that the tor browser uses?

Comment: I think you understand incorrectly.  Tor bridges do not use SOCKS, and you still have to use Tor to use a bridge.  If you need to get bridges, you can use the form at https://bridges.torproject.org/options.

Comment: Anyway to get a list of public SOCKS5 Tor proxies?

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [TransparentProxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy)

Also, try to read manual, you can do this by typing:

```
# man torrc
```

There is such information about transport's options:

> TransPort [address:]port|auto [isolation flags]
>     Open this port to listen for transparent proxy connections. Set this to 0 if you don’t want to allow transparent proxy
>   connections. Set the port to "auto" to have Tor pick a port for you.
>   This directive can be specified multiple times to bind to multiple
>   addresses/ports. If multiple entries of this
>              option are present in your configuration file, Tor will perform stream isolation between listeners by default. See SOCKSPort
>   for an explanation of isolation flags.
>
> TransPort requires OS support for transparent proxies, such as BSDs' pf or Linux’s IPTables. If you’re planning to use Tor as a
>   transparent proxy for a network, you’ll want to examine and change
>   VirtualAddrNetwork from the default setting. (Default: 0)

Also, you would like to google for `Tor-middle-box`, it shall be a little bit safer. In such scenario: lets suppose, there are little buggies inside linux kernel still && network stack && iptables.. and whatever.... So, in that way, your transparent proxy might blinks from time to time, there was such bad situation, earlier... And couple of your DNS requests, from-time-to-time goes right to google's DNS `4.2.2.2` in plain, from your real IP. Not fine, right?

However, `Tor-middle-box` - is a separate computer, often Raspberry-Pi based tiny tor-box, which convert all your traffic into Tor-network, like man-in-the-middle.

It is much easier to design really secure hardware isolated Tor-proxy, than construct something virtual with iptables or even LXC, etc...